# Will DTP always use the native VLAN or always VLAN 1?

Tags: cisco, switch, vlan, trunk

I'm having trouble understanding whether DTP will always use the native VLAN, even if it's configured to be non-default, or if it will use VLAN 1 in any case. For example, if you configured VLAN 50 to be your native VLAN, would DTP use VLAN 50, or continue on VLAN 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DTP doesn't actually use a VLAN because it is a local-link protocol that does not go beyond the endpoints of the links. The frames used by DTP are not tagged, so many people say that it uses the native VLAN, but if the native VLAN is used by other switch interfaces, the DTP frames will not be forwarded to those interfaces the way other frames in the native VLAN can be.

The current Cisco best practice is to not use a native VLAN or VLAN 1. The link-local frames for things like DTP, CDP, etc. will still reach the other end of the link and work.